# Linking to a specific thread using the Gmail API Thread Id

Tags: gmail-api

Using the Gmail API with OAuth, I can get a thread ID on behalf of a user. I'm interested in providing a link on a webpage for the user to navigate to view the thread itself on Gmail. Is there a way to actually navigate to a thread? Does each thread have its own URL and, if so, what is it?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: This isn't really a code problem. I have a thread ID from the API. I want to know if a url exists for the user to visit the thread in their gmail by using the Thread ID only.